# How to initialize a new object?

Tags: c#, class, object, constructor

I tried inserting the variable names into new NameClass2() but it still wont work.
I do not want to have the variables already given value like
NameClass2 newObject = new NameClass2("Book", new DateTime(2012, 02, 15, 12, 00, 00), 100, "fly");
I would like the user to able to give write his own

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp10
{
    public class NameClass1
    {
        public string Name1 { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date1 { get; set; }

        public int Const1 { get; set; }

        public NameClass1(string name1, DateTime date1, int const1)
        {
            this.Name1 = name1;
            this.Date1 = date1;
            this.Const1 = 100;
        }
    }

    public class NameClass2 : NameClass1
    {
        public string Name2 { get; set; }

        public NameClass2(string name1, DateTime date1, int const1, string name2) : base(name1, date1, const1)
        {
            this.Name2 = name2;
        }
    }

    class Program

    {

        static void Main(string[] args)

        {
            string stopCode = null;
            do
            {
                NameClass2 newObject = new NameClass2(); // it says there is no argument given

                Console.WriteLine("Name of stringa 1:");
                newObject.Name1 = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Date:");

                var stro = Console.ReadLine();
                DateTime dt;
                var isValidDate = DateTime.TryParse(stro, out dt);
                newObject.Date1 = dt;

                Console.WriteLine("Name of string 2:");
                newObject.Name2 = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("stop?");
                stopCode = Console.ReadLine();

            } while (stopCode != "stop");


        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You do not have an empty constructor. Once you define any constructor the default constructor disappears

Comment: hi, " I would like the user to able to give write his own" please write in pseudo code how you imagine this to be realized. The desired outcome is yet not clear to me

Comment: Documentations will help you. It has it all covered. On the left side you can see there's even more about constructors. Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors  It's like @DownloadPizza wrote - You need a parameterless constructor.

Comment: Save the values entered by the user into local variables and then create the object passing those variables in.

Comment: Try storing the values in a variable and pass it to the object.